# How can I close a specific file using a batch command

Tags: batch-file, automation, batch-processing

I'm trying to create a batch file that opens up an Access file. (Presses enter), and then closes the Access file again. I'm a complete noob  to batch file's, and the only part I got working was the open file part.

```
Start ""  "W:\Motorenfabriek\World Class Manufacturing\Verspaning\Area 1\PROVO Applicatie\Database tabellen\TblStoringDienst.accdb"
```

When I run this code the application opens. Problem is within the organisation you first have to press enter before you can work with your Access file.

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't seen any working answers yet.

I tried the code beneith to close the application again but this isn't working. The application stays opened:

```
taskill /f /im "W:\Motorenfabriek\World Class Manufacturing\Verspaning\Area 1\PROVO Applicatie\Database tabellen\TblStoringDienst.accdb"
```

I only want this file to close, not all Access instances because there is running another one aswell.

Comment: I found a way to get rid of the messagebox, so the automated enter isn't needed anymore. I still would like to know how you can exit a specific file with batch code.

Comment: Which other solution did you try? In what way did that not work for your case?

Comment: @HåkenLid I updated the question. Couldn't get code in the comment.

Comment: Good. Updating the question is the proper way to add details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to kill a task, one of the easier methods are to kill it by window title. So as an example, I have a file open called `test.txt` and the file is open in `notepad`. the title is displayed as `test.txt - Notepad`.

I can then just do this to kill it.

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq test.txt - Notepad" /T
```

The same will go for Window Titles such as:

```
my_devices.csv - Excel
My Document1 - Word
TblStoringDienst.accdb - Access
Hex edit TblStoringDienst.accdb
```

etc.

As for your send keystroke option, pure batch cannot do it, you have to do wscript and batch combination. This will send enter to the screen after a timeout of 2 sconds, when the command was started. It is untested as I do not have your environment, so might need to be tuned.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
        Start ""  "W:\Motorenfabriek\World Class Manufacturing\Verspaning\Area 1\PROVO Applicatie\Database tabellen\TblStoringDienst.accdb"
        timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
        %SendKeys% {ENTER}

@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, the code for the automated 'enter' works well. I still can't get the taskkill to work, but this is probably my fault. When I put the taskkill behind the code for the enter, the enter code won't work anymore.

Comment: @DennisvdEijnde perhaps put the taskkill in te very beginning, before the `if` statement.